# Is it possible to share compute instance with other user?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I create one compute instance 'yhd-notebook' in Azure Machine Learning compute with user1. When I login with user2, and try to open the JupyterLab of this compute instance, it shows an error message like below.

> User user2 does not have access to compute instance yhd-notebook.
>
> Only the creator can access a compute instance.
>
> Click here to sign out and sign in again with a different account.

Is it possible to share compute instance with another user? BTW, both user1 and user2 have Owner role with the Azure subscription.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to MS, all users in the workspace contributor and owner role can create, delete, start, stop, and restart compute instances across the workspace. However, only the creator of a specific compute instance is allowed to access Jupyter, JupyterLab, and RStudio on that compute instance. The creator of the compute instance has the compute instance dedicated to them, have root access, and can terminal in through Jupyter. Compute instance will have single-user login of creator user and all actions will use that user’s identity for RBAC and attribution of experiment runs. SSH access is controlled through public/private key mechanism.

Comment: Well, both user1 and user2 are my accounts. You know, sometimes we need more than one accounts for testing purpose. For me, compute instance is just another resouce in Azure, it would be good if Microsoft can make it sharable in the near future. Thanks.

Comment: Fully agreed. In my company, only a few people can actually create Azure resources but we want the whole analytics team to work with AML. And it would be ideal if the team can share a single compute instance.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a little on @hui chen's useful answer.

Although you can't share computer instances from azure's web interface you can access the compute instance's jupyter directly by sshing into them (note that ssh runs on port `50000`). jupyter runs on port `8888`.

I haven't experimented with the filesystem synchronization yet... so be careful. Also none of this is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

compute "instance" creator can assign that compute to some other user , but yes only one user can be assigned
On other hand , compute "cluster" is basically VM and can be shared across workspace users.
Remember compute cluster can not be used for ML notebooks, it can be used to train models for designer and pipelines